# Erlang mime type

Tags: file, erlang, mime

How can i know mime type of file with Erlang?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse MIME messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042330/parse-mime-messages)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know the mime type of a file based on its extension you can use the undocumented inets function `httpd_conf:load_mime_types/1`. This together with a `mime.types` file (there's one in one of the inets httpd examples in OTP) will give you a list of file extensions and their default associated mime types. The following code will give you the standard mime type for a given filename based on its extension:

```
mime_type(FileName) ->
    "." ++ Extension = filename:extension(FileName),
    MimeTypes = mime_types(),
    proplists:get_value(Extension, MimeTypes).

mime_types() ->
    MimeTypesFile = filename:join(code:lib_dir(inets), 
                                  "examples/server_root/conf/mime.types"),
    {ok, MimeTypes} = httpd_conf:load_mime_types(MimeTypesFile),
    MimeTypes.
```

You can now use `mime_type/1` on a filename (e.g. `example.pdf`) and it will return you the default mime type if known (in this case `"application/pdf"`) or `undefined` otherwise.

If you're going to do this operation repeatedly, it would be a good idea to cache the result of `httpd_conf:load_mime_types/1` as the `inets` `httpd` server does, so that you avoid reading and parsing the mime types file all the time.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you want. If it's not something critical you can be very unsophisticated and simply use the `file` command usually available in *NIX environments. It goes beyond guessing by file extension using several tests (file system, magic numbers, and text inspection).

```
1> os:cmd("file -i erl_crash.dump").
"erl_crash.dump: text/plain; charset=us-ascii\n"
```

You can get the bits you want parsing that output. It's pretty inefficient, since you spawn an OS process per call, but's dead simple.

If you need something efficient, you may want to write C driver (e.g. using libmagic) or a native implementation in erlang, but I'm not aware of any existing one.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use this:
 mochiweb_mime:from_extension(filename:extension(File))

> %% @author Bob Ippolito  %% @copyright 2007 Mochi
>   Media, Inc.
>
> %% @doc Gives a good MIME type guess based on file extension.
>
> -module(mochiweb_mime).
>   -author('bob@mochimedia.com').
>   -export([from_extension/1]).
>
> %% @spec from_extension(S::string()) -> string() | undefined %% @doc
>   Given a filename extension (e.g. ".html") return a guess for the MIME
>   %%      type such as "text/html". Will return the atom undefined if no
>   good %%      guess is available.
>
> from_extension(".stl") ->
>       "application/SLA"; from_extension(".stp") ->
>       "application/STEP"; from_extension(".step") ->
>       "application/STEP"; from_extension(".dwg") ->
>       "application/acad"; from_extension(".ez") ->
>       "application/andrew-inset"; from_extension(".ccad") ->
>       "application/clariscad"; from_extension(".drw") ->
>       "application/drafting"; from_extension(".tsp") ->
>       "application/dsptype"; from_extension(".dxf") ->
>       "application/dxf"; from_extension(".xls") ->
>       "application/excel"; from_extension(".unv") ->
>       "application/i-deas"; from_extension(".jar") ->
>       "application/java-archive"; from_extension(".hqx") ->
>       "application/mac-binhex40"; from_extension(".cpt") ->
>       "application/mac-compactpro"; from_extension(".pot") ->
>       "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; from_extension(".ppt") ->
>       "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; from_extension(".dms") ->
>       "application/octet-stream"; from_extension(".lha") ->
>       "application/octet-stream"; from_extension(".lzh") ->
>       "application/octet-stream"; from_extension(".oda") ->
>       "application/oda"; from_extension(".ogg") ->
>       "application/ogg"; from_extension(".ogm") ->
>       "application/ogg"; from_extension(".pdf") ->
>       "application/pdf"; from_extension(".pgp") ->
>       "application/pgp"; from_extension(".ai") ->
>       "application/postscript"; from_extension(".eps") ->
>       "application/postscript"; from_extension(".ps") ->
>       "application/postscript"; from_extension(".prt") ->
>       "application/pro_eng"; from_extension(".rtf") ->
>       "application/rtf"; from_extension(".smi") ->
>       "application/smil"; from_extension(".smil") ->
>       "application/smil"; from_extension(".sol") ->
>       "application/solids"; from_extension(".vda") ->
>       "application/vda"; from_extension(".xlm") ->
>       "application/vnd.ms-excel"; from_extension(".cod") ->
>       "application/vnd.rim.cod"; from_extension(".pgn") ->
>       "application/x-chess-pgn"; from_extension(".cpio") ->
>       "application/x-cpio"; from_extension(".csh") ->
>       "application/x-csh"; from_extension(".deb") ->
>       "application/x-debian-package"; from_extension(".dcr") ->
>       "application/x-director"; from_extension(".dir") ->
>       "application/x-director"; from_extension(".dxr") ->
>       "application/x-director"; from_extension(".gz") ->
>       "application/x-gzip"; from_extension(".hdf") ->
>       "application/x-hdf"; from_extension(".ipx") ->
>       "application/x-ipix"; from_extension(".ips") ->
>       "application/x-ipscript"; from_extension(".js") ->
>       "application/x-javascript"; from_extension(".skd") ->
>       "application/x-koan"; from_extension(".skm") ->
>       "application/x-koan"; from_extension(".skp") ->
>       "application/x-koan"; from_extension(".skt") ->
>       "application/x-koan"; from_extension(".latex") ->
>       "application/x-latex"; from_extension(".lsp") ->
>       "application/x-lisp"; from_extension(".scm") ->
>       "application/x-lotusscreencam"; from_extension(".mif") ->
>       "application/x-mif"; from_extension(".com") ->
>       "application/x-msdos-program"; from_extension(".exe") ->
>       "application/octet-stream"; from_extension(".cdf") ->
>       "application/x-netcdf"; from_extension(".nc") ->
>       "application/x-netcdf"; from_extension(".pl") ->
>       "application/x-perl"; from_extension(".pm") ->
>       "application/x-perl"; from_extension(".rar") ->
>       "application/x-rar-compressed"; from_extension(".sh") ->
>       "application/x-sh"; from_extension(".shar") ->
>       "application/x-shar"; from_extension(".swf") ->
>       "application/x-shockwave-flash"; from_extension(".sit") ->
>       "application/x-stuffit"; from_extension(".sv4cpio") ->
>       "application/x-sv4cpio"; from_extension(".sv4crc") ->
>       "application/x-sv4crc"; from_extension(".tar.gz") ->
>       "application/x-tar-gz"; from_extension(".tgz") ->
>       "application/x-tar-gz"; from_extension(".tar") ->
>       "application/x-tar"; from_extension(".tcl") ->
>       "application/x-tcl"; from_extension(".texi") ->
>       "application/x-texinfo"; from_extension(".texinfo") ->
>       "application/x-texinfo"; from_extension(".man") ->
>       "application/x-troff-man"; from_extension(".me") ->
>       "application/x-troff-me"; from_extension(".ms") ->
>       "application/x-troff-ms"; from_extension(".roff") ->
>       "application/x-troff"; from_extension(".t") ->
>       "application/x-troff"; from_extension(".tr") ->
>       "application/x-troff"; from_extension(".ustar") ->
>       "application/x-ustar"; from_extension(".src") ->
>       "application/x-wais-source"; from_extension(".zip") ->
>       "application/zip"; from_extension(".tsi") ->
>       "audio/TSP-audio"; from_extension(".au") ->
>       "audio/basic"; from_extension(".snd") ->
>       "audio/basic"; from_extension(".kar") ->
>       "audio/midi"; from_extension(".mid") ->
>       "audio/midi"; from_extension(".midi") ->
>       "audio/midi"; from_extension(".mp2") ->
>       "audio/mpeg"; from_extension(".mp3") ->
>       "audio/mpeg"; from_extension(".mpga") ->
>       "audio/mpeg"; from_extension(".aif") ->
>       "audio/x-aiff"; from_extension(".aifc") ->
>       "audio/x-aiff"; from_extension(".aiff") ->
>       "audio/x-aiff"; from_extension(".m3u") ->
>       "audio/x-mpegurl"; from_extension(".wax") ->
>       "audio/x-ms-wax"; from_extension(".wma") ->
>       "audio/x-ms-wma"; from_extension(".rpm") ->
>       "audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin"; from_extension(".ram") ->
>       "audio/x-pn-realaudio"; from_extension(".rm") ->
>       "audio/x-pn-realaudio"; from_extension(".ra") ->
>       "audio/x-realaudio"; from_extension(".wav") ->
>       "audio/x-wav"; from_extension(".pdb") ->
>       "chemical/x-pdb"; from_extension(".ras") ->
>       "image/cmu-raster"; from_extension(".gif") ->
>       "image/gif"; from_extension(".ief") ->
>       "image/ief"; from_extension(".jpe") ->
>       "image/jpeg"; from_extension(".jpeg") ->
>       "image/jpeg"; from_extension(".jpg") ->
>       "image/jpeg"; from_extension(".jp2") ->
>       "image/jp2"; from_extension(".png") ->
>       "image/png"; from_extension(".tif") ->
>       "image/tiff"; from_extension(".tiff") ->
>       "image/tiff"; from_extension(".pnm") ->
>       "image/x-portable-anymap"; from_extension(".pbm") ->
>       "image/x-portable-bitmap"; from_extension(".pgm") ->
>       "image/x-portable-graymap"; from_extension(".ppm") ->
>       "image/x-portable-pixmap"; from_extension(".rgb") ->
>       "image/x-rgb"; from_extension(".xbm") ->
>       "image/x-xbitmap"; from_extension(".xwd") ->
>       "image/x-xwindowdump"; from_extension(".iges") ->
>       "model/iges"; from_extension(".igs") ->
>       "model/iges"; from_extension(".mesh") ->
>       "model/mesh"; from_extension(".") ->
>       ""; from_extension(".msh") ->
>       "model/mesh"; from_extension(".silo") ->
>       "model/mesh"; from_extension(".vrml") ->
>       "model/vrml"; from_extension(".wrl") ->
>       "model/vrml"; from_extension(".css") ->
>       "text/css"; from_extension(".htm") ->
>       "text/html"; from_extension(".html") ->
>       "text/html"; from_extension(".asc") ->
>       "text/plain"; from_extension(".c") ->
>       "text/plain"; from_extension(".cc") ->
>       "text/plain"; from_extension(".f90") ->
>       "text/plain"; from_extension(".f") ->
>       "text/plain"; from_extension(".hh") ->
>       "text/plain"; from_extension(".m") ->
>       "text/plain"; from_extension(".txt") ->
>       "text/plain"; from_extension(".rtx") ->
>       "text/richtext"; from_extension(".sgm") ->
>       "text/sgml"; from_extension(".sgml") ->
>       "text/sgml"; from_extension(".tsv") ->
>       "text/tab-separated-values"; from_extension(".jad") ->
>       "text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor"; from_extension(".etx") ->
>       "text/x-setext"; from_extension(".xml") ->
>       "application/xml"; from_extension(".dl") ->
>       "video/dl"; from_extension(".fli") ->
>       "video/fli"; from_extension(".flv") ->
>       "video/flv"; from_extension(".gl") ->
>       "video/gl"; from_extension(".mp4") ->
>       "video/mp4"; from_extension(".mpe") ->
>       "video/mpeg"; from_extension(".mpeg") ->
>       "video/mpeg"; from_extension(".mpg") ->
>       "video/mpeg"; from_extension(".mov") ->
>       "video/quicktime"; from_extension(".qt") ->
>       "video/quicktime"; from_extension(".viv") ->
>       "video/vnd.vivo"; from_extension(".vivo") ->
>       "video/vnd.vivo"; from_extension(".asf") ->
>       "video/x-ms-asf"; from_extension(".asx") ->
>       "video/x-ms-asx"; from_extension(".wmv") ->
>       "video/x-ms-wmv"; from_extension(".wmx") ->
>       "video/x-ms-wmx"; from_extension(".wvx") ->
>       "video/x-ms-wvx"; from_extension(".avi") ->
>       "video/x-msvideo"; from_extension(".movie") ->
>       "video/x-sgi-movie"; from_extension(".mime") ->
>       "www/mime"; from_extension(".ice") ->
>       "x-conference/x-cooltalk"; from_extension(".vrm") ->
>       "x-world/x-vrml"; from_extension(".spx") ->
>       "audio/ogg"; from_extension(".xhtml") ->
>       "application/xhtml+xml"; from_extension(".bz2") ->
>       "application/x-bzip2"; from_extension(".doc") ->
>       "application/msword"; from_extension(".z") ->
>       "application/x-compress"; from_extension(".ico") ->
>       "image/x-icon"; from_extension(".bmp") ->
>       "image/bmp"; from_extension(".m4a") ->
>       "audio/mpeg"; from_extension(".csv") ->
>       "text/csv"; from_extension(_) ->
>       undefined.
>
> %% %% Tests %%
>   -ifdef(TEST).
>   -include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").
>
> exhaustive_from_extension_test() ->
>       T = mochiweb_cover:clause_lookup_table(?MODULE, from_extension),
>       [?assertEqual(V, from_extension(K)) || {K, V} <- T].
>
> from_extension_test() ->
>       ?assertEqual("text/html",
>                    from_extension(".html")),
>       ?assertEqual(undefined,
>                    from_extension("")),
>       ?assertEqual(undefined,
>                    from_extension(".wtf")),
>       ok.
>
> -endif.